# Why we are not using .click(); for select class

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

This is my code and [URL](https://www.facebook.com/). This code is working fine my doubt is why we are not using `.click();` in below code:

```
Select s1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month")));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Select` class just provides a convenient abstraction layer over the `select` and `option` elements. Internally, though, the `selectBy*` methods still do the proper clicking ([source code reference](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.java)):

```
private void setSelected(WebElement option, boolean select) {
  boolean isSelected=option.isSelected();
  if ((!isSelected && select) || (isSelected && !select)) {
    option.click();  // < HERE!
  }
}
```

It is just encapsulated inside the `Select` class implementation.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the Select class has this constructor:

```
Select(WebElement element)
```

Moreover logically you won't be selecting `Select tag`..you would be selecting `options`...so there are various methods defined to select options in different ways..see [Reference Docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.java)
All methods defined here to select options, include this method internally...

```
private void setSelected(WebElement option, boolean select) {
    boolean isSelected=option.isSelected();
    if ((!isSelected && select) || (isSelected && !select)) {
      option.click();
    }
  }
```

So if you call one of those methods...e.g.`selectByIndex(int index)` they will include click internally.

Answer (score 0):

In the automation testing company elements that have 'SELECT TAG' in it to select these elements we use Select select = new Select(WebElement element). Then we perform the desired action using select functions select.selectByVisibleText(string text).

As in https://www.facebook.com/ we have select tag for Day, Month and Year for Birthday section we use below code for selecting month from the drop down.(Say Jan)

```
Select s1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month")));
s1.select.selectByVisibleText("Jan");
```

**Note: *In select functions selectByVisibleText(), selectByValue() and selectByIndex(),We do not use click(), As select functions already have click() inside the wrapper methods*.**

Pre defined Select function example that already contains click().

```
public void selectByIndex(int index) {
    String match = String.valueOf(index);

    boolean matched = false;
    for (WebElement option : getOptions()) {
      if (match.equals(option.getAttribute("index"))) {
        setSelected(option);
        if (!isMultiple()) {
          return;
        }
        matched = true;
      }
    }
    if (!matched) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate option with index: " + index);
    }
  }


 private void setSelected(WebElement option) {
    if (!option.isSelected()) {
      option.click();
    }
  }
```

Hoping this may clear the doubt

Thanks